# Sql query to get default value as 0 for a particular column

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a issue with a query.

My query is :-

```
SELECT MONTH(o.OrderDate) as MonthValue, 
       YEAR(o.OrderDate) as YearValue, 
       C.CustomerTypeID, Count(o.Total) as NoOfOrders
FROM Orders o        
RIGHT JOIN Customers C on C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID      

WHERE o.OrderDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 00:00:00 AM')
AND o.OrderDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 23:59:59 PM')
GROUP BY MONTH(o.OrderDate), 
         YEAR(o.OrderDate), 
         C.CustomerTypeID 
ORDER BY MONTH(o.OrderDate),
         YEAR(o.OrderDate),
         C.CustomerTypeID
```

It is giving result as follows :-

```
MonthValue   YearValue   CustomerTypeID   NoOfOrders
1              2013            1             10
1              2013            2             20
1              2013            3             45
2              2013            1             45
2              2013            2             45
3              2013            1             88
3              2013            2             56
3              2013            3             89
```

As for month 2, customer type 3 has no result, so it is not appears in result.

But I want to show "0" as a default result for it, like below :-

```
2              2013            3             0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried left join to get the row to show up and isnull to handle the null value?

Comment: Thanks @Brandon for quick replay, but there is no NULL value, as customer type 3 not have any order in 2'nd month, so it is not appearing in result.

Comment: Your `RIGHT JOIN` does not make sense because an Order should belong to a Customer, right? Have you tried `LEFT JOIN` instead, that is, a Customer with orders or not should be displayed and those who have no orders would have 0 as `NoOfOrders`?

Comment: Yes @Edper, I tried but same result.

Comment: @AnandMeena are you sure that there is CustomerTypeID = 3 in the 2nd month? Could you show your actual data (if you allow it)?

Comment: @Edper, Yes I am sure, But I can't show actual data here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT  2013 as [Year],
        months.number,
        Amount = SUM(COALESCE(o.Total,0)),
        C.CustomerType
FROM    Customers C
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='p' and number between 1 and 12) months
LEFT JOIN [Orders] o on C.CustomerId = o.CustomerId and YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2013 and MONTH(o.OrderDate) = months.number
GROUP BY months.number, C.CustomerType 
ORDER BY months.number, C.CustomerType
```

Comment: Thanks @Nisarg, It is working fine, I was looking struggling from 4 hours, thanks you are the champ :-)

Comment: Now, If want to get 52 weeks data of a year than? can you help me?

Comment: Need to check for week wise.I will back to you soon.

Comment: For week, you just need to replace MONTH(o.OrderDate) with DATEPART(wk, o.OrderDate) and range will be changed from 1 to 52.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: You must outer join all months do get the missing entries. So for best readability cross join all customers and months first and then outer join the orders.

```
SELECT all_months.MonthValue, 
       all_months.YearValue, 
       C.CustomerTypeID,
       Count(o.Total) as NoOfOrders
FROM 
(
  SELECT distinct MONTH(OrderDate) as MonthValue, YEAR(OrderDate) as YearValue
  FROM orders 
  WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2013
) all_months        
CROSS JOIN Customers C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o 
  ON o.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
  AND MONTH(o.OrderDate) = all_months.MonthValue 
  AND YEAR(o.OrderDate) = all_months.YearValue
GROUP BY all_months.MonthValue, 
         all_months.YearValue, 
         C.CustomerTypeID 
ORDER BY all_months.MonthValue,
         all_months.YearValue,
         C.CustomerTypeID ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten, but it is giving error, please see http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/afc7e4f5-7c6e-4ceb-9d3d-1a868e4d9a33/a9b7f89a2f03e3caae6079a8eb48f21a

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take much time to write this, so it came out rather sloppy. I've written it anew, so it should hopefully work now.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten :-), It is working fine now. Can we get 52 weeks data of a year ?

Comment: Hi, you get the month with MONTH(OrderDate), but there is no WEEK(OrderDate) for weeks. You would get the week by using DATEPART(wk, OrderDate) or DATEPART(isowk, OrderDate) instead. But read this closely: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174420.aspx?ppud=4 , because there are deiiferent views on what is week 1 and what is week 52 or even 53.

Comment: In case not every month (or week for that matter) is present in table orders, you would have to generate the numbers instead. Search for techniques on how to generate numbers in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could probably do a full outer join which should give you all of the customers, retuning null for the missing data. You could then select ISNULL(NoOfOrders, 0) to get 0 instead of a null.

I'm not 100& sure that would work, but you could give it a try.